# Multiple people on different PCs signing into a single user account

Tags: office365

(I asked this originally on Stack Exchange and was advised to post here.  Sorry for Cross-Post.)

Can a small office environment use Office 365 (with Access DB) in such a way that:

2 managers can have a "management user" account they can log in with on 2 different PCs. (Editing and running reports)

2 admins can have a "admin user" account they can log in with on 2 different PCs. (Adding and editing data)

6 engineers use a "viewer-only user" account - for out in the field - so they can log in from anywhere eg. phone.

So in effect, purchase 3 accounts for 3 different ROLES - even though it is for 10 people.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Office 365 questions are about web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is against the terms of service.  The licensing for Office 365 Business in one license per *named* user.  Named means it is assigned to a real person.  A role is not a named user.

The home version lets multiple people use one license. However, using the home version in a business is against the ToS.

Everyone is always thinking of a legal way or loophole to get the most out of something.  I might be able to do amazing things with computers, but I dont think for a second I can pull a fast one on Microsoft's droves of lawyers.

Comment: Crackin' last line! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help - I felt 'dirty' asking.  But my frugal customer was asking ;)